# Covid 19. Who says גַּדְּלוּ לה' אִתִּי and יְהַלְלוּ אֶת שֵׁם ה?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, sefer-torah

During the Covid 19 situation, in our shul the Baal Koreh takes out the Sefer Torah out and the person who does Hagbah takes it back. (The idea is to minimise the number of times the sefer is handled.)

Under normal conditions in many shuls, the Chazzan takes the Sefer Torah in his hand from the person who opened the Ark and later from the person who did Hagbah. The Chazzan then says the appropriate prayers related to that ceremony (weekdays גַּדְּלוּ לה' אִתִּי וּנְרומְמָה שְׁמו יַחְדָּו: and later
יְהַלְלוּ אֶת שֵׁם ה'. כִּי נִשגָּב שְׁמו לְבַדּו: )

The question is whether there is any guidance in the sources as to whether during the present or similar situation, these prayers are said by the person holding the Sefer at that time or by the Chazzan?

Comment: This also happens in more normal circumstances, if the chazzan is not strong enough to carry the sefer torah, and in many nusach sefard shuls when returning the sefer torah on a weekday.

Comment: Yes - and what is the practice then please?

Comment: I think I've always seen the chazzan say it, but I have no source (and I could be misremembering)